# How do i make an repeat button that cycles through repeat all and repeat one for an android music player?

Tags: java, android

This is my code I have got repeat one working but I want to be able to repeat all songs so it does not stop playing the music, I also want to be able to repeat one single song. I have tried to find documentation to help me but I haven't found anything. Any help would be appreciated

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
    private static final int STEP_VALUE = 5000;
    private static final int CALL = 872;
    static MediaPlayer mp = null;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private TextView selectedFile;
    private TextView selectedArtist;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private ImageButton playButton;
    private ImageButton prevButton;
    private ImageButton nextButton;
    private ImageButton repeatButton;
    private ImageButton shuffleButton;
    private boolean isStarted = true;
    private int currentPosition;
    private boolean isMovingSeekBar = false;
    private MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updatePosition();
        }
    };
    private List<Music> musicList;

    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.play:
                    if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                        player.pause();
                        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                    } else {
                        if (isStarted) {
                            player.start();
                            playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

                            updatePosition();
                        } else {
                            startPlay(currentPosition);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case R.id.prev:
                    startPlay(currentPosition - 1);


                    break;


                case R.id.next:
                    startPlay(currentPosition + 1);

                    break;


                case R.id.shuffle:
                    if (isShuffle) {
                        Collections.shuffle(musicList);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        shuffleButton.setColorFilter(-16776961);
                    } else {
                        sortMusicList();
                        shuffleButton.setColorFilter(-16777216);
                    }

                    isShuffle = !isShuffle;
                    break;

                case R.id.repeat: {
                    if (isRepeat) {
                        player.setLooping(true);
                        repeatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_repeat_black_24dp);
                        repeatButton.setColorFilter(-16776961);
                    } else {
                        player.setLooping(false);
                        repeatButton.setColorFilter(-16777216);
                    }

                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    };

    private void sortMusicList() {
        Collections.sort(musicList, new Comparator<Music>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Music o1, Music o2) {
                return o1.getArtists().compareTo(o2.getArtists());
            }
        });

        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            stopPlay();
            startPlay(currentPosition + 1);
        }

    };
    private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

            return false;
        }
    };
    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isMovingSeekBar = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isMovingSeekBar = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (isMovingSeekBar) {
                player.seekTo(progress);

                Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener", "onProgressChanged");
            } else {
                TextView duration = findViewById(R.id.song_duration);
                duration.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                long totalSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(progress);
                long minss = totalSeconds / 60;
                long seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

                duration.setText(String.format(Locale.UK, "%02d:%02d", minss, seconds));
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));


        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setupUI();
        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    CALL);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        player.getCurrentPosition();
    }


    private void setupUI() {
        selectedFile = findViewById(R.id.selected_file);
        selectedArtist = findViewById(R.id.artists);
        seekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        prevButton = findViewById(R.id.prev);
        playButton = findViewById(R.id.play);
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next);
        repeatButton = findViewById(R.id.repeat);
        shuffleButton = findViewById(R.id.shuffle);


        player = new MediaPlayer();

        player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);

        player.setOnErrorListener(onError);

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);


        musicList = new MusicManager().getMusic(getContentResolver());
        sortMusicList();

        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(musicList);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                startPlay(position);
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prevButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        shuffleButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        repeatButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();

        player = null;
    }

    private void startPlay(int position) {
        if (position < 0) {
            position = 0;
        }
        if (position >= musicList.size()) {
            position = musicList.size() - 1;
        }
        String file = musicList.get(position).getFile();
        String title = musicList.get(position).getTitle();
        String artists = musicList.get(position).getArtists();

        currentPosition = position;
        if (artists != null) {
            selectedArtist.setText(artists);
        }
        if (title != null) {
            selectedFile.setText(title);
        }


        seekbar.setProgress(0);
        updatePosition();

        player.stop();
        player.reset();

        try {
            player.setDataSource(file);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);


        isStarted = true;
    }

    private void stopPlay() {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        playButton.setImageResource(ic_media_play);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);

        isStarted = false;
    }

    private void updatePosition() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);

        seekbar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

        handler.postDelayed(updatePositionRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);

        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }

    }


}
```

this is just the main activity if you need anything else just ask.

Answer (score 0):

To play a list of songs loop continuously, you can define a variable to be used as an index of the number of songs completed. After completion of the of the list, replay the list of songs by calling the index again. An example of this is:

```
int[] myAudio = {R.raw.audio1, R.raw.audio2, R.raw.audio3};
int mSongFinish = 0;

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myAudio[0]);

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mSongFinish++;
    mp.reset();
    if (mSongFinish < myAudio.length()) {
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor asset = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myAudio[mSongFinish]);
            if (asset != null) {
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), asset.getStartOffset(), asset.getLength());
                asset.close();
                mp.prepare();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // report a crash
        }
    } else {
        mSongFinish=0;
        mp.release();
        mp = null;     // either set counter to 0 and start again or call end of list

    }
}
});
mp.start();
```

To do this on a button click, just use an onClickListener. To loop a single song on button click, use `mp.setLooping(true)`.

Comment: It seems you have already implemented the looping of a single song. If that's not what you meant, please explain your question further.

Comment: I meant repeating the whole list of songs and if you could how can i cycle through it so eg repeat all songs repeat one song then stop repeating

Comment: The answer above repeats the whole list of songs. Have you tried it?

Comment: Okay. Just confirming, you mean you want to loop the whole song list and then loop one single song after that and then stop looping, on a button click?

Comment: What i meant was on one button click it is repeating all songs on the second button click it repeats one song on the third button click it stops looping altogether

Comment: Okay. You can use one toggle button for looping/stop looping all songs and another toggle button that loops/stops looping single song. This would be a better approach than three different buttons. The answer above already explains how to loop multiple songs and a single song.

Comment: I meant in 1 button so eg the button is off nothing is repeating then i press it and its highlighted to show its repeating all songs then i press the same button again and it repeats only one button then if i press it again it stop repeating altogether

Comment: For that you could use multiple if-else cases. Anyway, did the above answer solve the question?

Comment: no it sadly didnt i wanted the repeat all songs to be in the r.id.repeat in an if statement

Comment: Since isRepeat is a boolean, you can only define two functions for it. To create a button with 3 functions, you can use a compound button or a multi state toggle button. [This library](https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton) is perfect solution for that. After this, simply call the methods within onCompletionListener in the button onClick as the first state, add setLooping(true) for the second state and setLooping(false) for the third.

Comment: but the repeat button is an image meaning it will be removed

Comment: You can take a look into this answer. However it is a hacky method and may not be stable. Another method would be to define separate variables depending on the case and then assign its respective function.

Comment: could you please help me understand how to use arbitrary buttons with multi state toggle buttons.

Comment: Take a look into the [example](https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton/tree/master/example) given in the docs.